# Create CompletableFuture from a sync method call

Tags: java, asynchronous, lambda, java-8, completable-future

I would like to know if a one-liner exists for creating a CompletableFuture from a synchron method call. If no, why?

Long version:

```
final CompletableFuture<ReturnType> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
final String parameters = "hello";
ReturnType result;
try {
    result = syncMethodCall(parameters);
} catch (Exception e) {
    future.completeExceptionally(e);
}
future.complete(result);
return future;
```

Short desired version (or kind):

```
final String parameters = "hello";
return CompletableFuture.superMethod(() -> {syncMethodCall(parameters)});
```

Comment: `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(syncMethodCall(parameters))`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if `syncMethodCall` throws an exception, this exception is not stored in the CompletableFuture.

Comment: Your long version is fine. To convert it to a short version, just define your own "superMethod" with parameter of type Callable<T>.

Answer (score 12):

Since you accepted an answer that performs an asynchronous call, it’s unclear why you asked for a “synchron method call” in the first place. The task of performing an asynchronous method invocation is quite easy with `CompletableFuture`:

```
String parameters="hello";
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> syncMethodCall(parameters));
```

If your intention was to enforce the future to be already completed upon returning, it’s easy to enforce:

```
String parameters="hello";
CompletableFuture<ReturnType> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                                      () -> syncMethodCall(parameters));
f.handle((x,y) -> null).join();
return f;
```

The `handle` stage before the `join` ensures that in case `syncMethodCall` threw an exception, `join` won’t, as that seems to be your intention. But the `handle` stage is not returned, instead, the original future with the recorded exception will be returned.
Note that there’s a trick to do everything within the caller’s thread with the current implementation:

```
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("hello")
    .thenApply(parameters -> syncMethodCall(parameters));
```

The function passed to `thenApply` will be evaluated immediately when the future is already completed. But still, exceptions thrown by `syncMethodCall` are recorded in the returned future. So the outcome is identical to the “long version” of your question.

Comment: Thanks you very much.
I find the first answer ok to me (even with async) and I finally realized that using ForkJoinPool is not ok for me (using a vertx architecture I want only vertx threads)

Comment: what about exception handling? Should the code throw only RuntimeExceptions?

Comment: I’m afraid, the entire API is built around functional interfaces not allowing checked exceptions. If your method throws checked exceptions, you have to stay with your long version, of course, you could wrap your long version into a reusable utility method. For the actual action, you have to pick (or create) a functional interface allowing checked exception then, e.g. `Callable`…

Comment: Ok in fact, the last example with .thenApply(parameters -> syncMethodCall(parameters)) require syncHethodCall to return a CompletableFuture, which is not ok for me

Comment: @user1660655: I don’t see why it should require that.

Comment: Because in the long version, syncMethodCall return type is ReturnType. Like my legacy code.

Comment: In all of my code examples, the return type of `syncMethodCall` is assumed to be `ReturnType`. That includes the last example. It is *never* required to be a `CompletableFuture`. Why do you claim otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want that your CompletableFuture is completed with a result of some method call, and you do not want to complete that CompletableFuture yourself - then you need not CompletableFuture  - any Future implementation would be ok.
For example,

```
T function(parameters) {
  return new T();
}
T res1 = function(parameters); // sync call
Future<T> f = ForkJoinPool.commonPool.submit(() -> function(parameters));  // async call
T res2 =  f.get();
assert(res1.equals(res2));
```

Comment: Thanks you Alexei, ForkJoinPool, yeah!

Comment: Why the solution must be multi-threaded where the long version was not?

Comment: @user1660655 It is multithreaded because using Future (and CompletableFuture ) have no sense in sequential world.

Comment: It have this sense for me: handling some synchronous code the same way the rest (async) of the code is. Don't know if thats perfect but sounds good in my case