# Create CompletableFuture from blocking method call

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, completable-future

How can I "convert" a blocking method call to a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)? Example:

```
T waitForResult() throws InterruptedException {
    obj.await(); // blocking call
    // ...
    return something;
}
```

I need to turn that into this:

```
CompletableFuture.of(this::waitForResult); // .of(Callable<T>) doesn't exist
```

Some things to consider:

1. `waitForResult()` may throw exceptions. These have to be handled correctly, so that `completableFuture.get()` would throw an `InterruptedException` or an `ExecutionException`.
2. There must not be another thread involved (`supplyAsync()` would do so).
3. It must be a CompletableFuture (possibly wrapped).

I tried this, but this won't handle exceptions correctly:

```
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Void.TYPE).thenApply(v -> {
    try {
        listener.await();
        // ...
        return listener.getResult();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (SnmpException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
```

I know [Create CompletableFuture from a sync method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863100/create-completablefuture-from-a-sync-method-call), but it doesn't help me:

- The original code in the question blocks the main thread
- The code in the answers either incorporates a third thread or doesn't handle exceptions correctly (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Do I have to subclass CompletableFuture?

Comment: Can you clarify about point `2.` , "there must be no other thread involved"? Which thread should call (and wait on) `obj.await()` ? If it is the thread running `main`; then you block the main thread. Otherwise, you *need* to involve another thread. And in this case, supplyAsynch will probably be ok

Comment: @Daniele There's a main thread building the CompletableFuture, a second thread that later calls `get()` which in turns runs the callable (resulting in `listener.await()`). A third thread would be started when using `supplyAsync()`.

Comment: So you want the "main" thread to create the CompletableFuture; you have a second thread calling future.get(); and as part of calling get(), that second thread will also execute `listener.await()`. Is that right?

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding. Calling `get()` does *not* cause the callable to be invoked. Calling `get()` only makes the caller waiting for the result, whether there is an attempt to provide it or not. When your main thread is supposed to call `listener.await()`, it must do so; it will not know whether anyone has invoked `get()` on the future or not. — Besides that, when the second thread is supposed to call `get()` on the future created by the first one, the first thread must somehow hand over the future to the second thread.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your comment. But I believe there's no fundamental misunderstanding: What you describe is exactly what I want. The second thread blocks on `get()` waiting for the outcome, and sort of "expects" to wait. This blocking should be bound (or "forwarded") to the `await()` method. (Of course there's a third thread involved triggering the `await()` to proceed. Of course it may have finished already.)

Comment: This sounds like you want something like: • Thread A: create `CompletableFuture` via `new CompletableFuture<>()`, handing it over to thread B, perhaps doing something else, then calling `listener.await(); future.complete(listener.getResult());` • Thread B: receiving the `CompletableFuture` from thread A, perhaps doing something else, then calling `future.get();`.

Comment: you have to rework the method await: replace in it all blocking calls to non-blocking. This can be impossible, if it calls some blocking methods from a library which you cannot refactor.

Comment: @Holger Yes. The main thing is, that when building the CompletableFuture, Thread A must not wait for the result, but it should be able to `get()` it later (as in my code fragment). I guess, Thread B doesn't play a big role here.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Let's assume, the listener (which declares `await()`) contains all necessary methods I would need here. (In this case, the listener has an inner CountDownLatch.)

Comment: @steffen CountDownLatch belongs to the library you cannot modify :). But you can create its asynchronous analogue, see my answer.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Yes, but a CountDownLatch has get(TimeOut). Also, the listener could use another class for the inner logic.

Comment: @steffen CompletableFuture also has get(TimeOut). If you want to use asynchronous timeouts with CompletableFuture, see http://iteratrlearning.com/java9/2016/09/13/java9-timeouts-completablefutures.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements. Does this meet them?

```
private <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplySynchronously(Callable<T> callable) {
    CompletableFuture<T> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
    try {
        f.complete(callable.call());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        f.completeExceptionally(e);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Here, the main thread building the CompletableFuture will get blocked because it calls `callable.call()` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, its an big abuse of CompletableFuture but you have to decide if its acceptable for your use case:

```
private static <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplySynchronously(Callable<T> callable) {
    CompletableFuture<T> f = new CompletableFuture() {

        public T get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            synchronized (callable) {
                if (!isDone()) {
                    try {
                        T result = callable.call();
                        complete(result);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        completeExceptionally(e);
                    }

                }
            }
            return (T) super.get();
        }
    };
    return f;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was expecting: I have to subclass CompletableFuture. I'm just very unsure if overriding `get()` is the correct way to do so. Your code seems correct to me. (You could use an extra Lock object instead of synchronizing on the Callable.)

Comment: Why do you think this is a big abuse?

Comment: Yes, its better to use extra lock instead of locking on callable(someone else can accidentally lock on that object also). I mean abuse in sense that the creator of that class didnt expect that we will use it in this way. I think we have to override get() method, to mimic the same behaviour as normal Completable future in sense that the callable will be called only once and either result is set or excpetion is set. Also if someone cancel the future before it works as expected.

Comment: I agree. That's why I was searching for an alternative to subclassing CompletableFuture. Here, for example, `isDone()` doesn't work, because `get()` *has* to be called first to produce a result.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, I think you have to call isDone() otherwise it would be possible to call the callable two times.

Comment: In the code you wrote, yes, of course. But you can't call 'isDone()` before or in place of `get()`. `isDone()` will always return false. The result will become available only *after* `get()` was called. So if `await()` would return immediately because the result is already there, `isDone()` will still return false. An example implementation for `isDone()`: `return listener.await(0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)`.

Comment: Not only `isDone()` doesn’t work. Neither does `join()` nor `.thenApply(…).get()`, or in short, *everything* besides calling `get()` won’t work.

Comment: @Holger Yep :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let the method `Listener.await()` invokes method `CountDownLatch.await()`:

```
class Listener {
   CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(counter);

   void someMethod(){
     latch.countdown();
   }

   public void await() {
      latch.await();
   }
}
```

then you can convert it to an asynchronous in following way:

```
class Listener {
   AsynCountDownLatch latch = new AsynCountDownLatch(counter);

   void someMethod(){ // here nothing changed
     latch.countdown();
   }

   public CompletableFuture<Void> async() {
      return latch.fin;
   }
}

class AsynCountDownLatch extends AsynCountDownLatch {
   CompletableFuture<Void> fin = new CompletableFuture<>();

   public AsynCountDownLatch(long counter) {
     super(counter);
   }

   public void countdown() {
       super.countdown();
       if (super.getCount()==0L) {
           fin.complete(null);
       }
   }
 }
```

UPDT:  if the listener uses another class, then that class also has to be modified/extended/replaced to convert blocking operations to non-blocking. There is no universal way to do such a conversion.

Comment: Yes, I think this is also possible! I'll check that when I'm back at work.